# Clean architecture current user acquisition

Tags: authentication, authorization, cqrs, clean-architecture

Should in Clean Architecture use cases be aware of the authentication/authorization process and command/query layer should have some abstraction of the authentication service implemented in layer below using some framework or user identifier should be passed as the part of the command/query?

Options:

Option 1:

```
class ChangePasswordCommand {

    char[] newPassword;
}

class ChangePasswordCommandHandler {

    AuthService authService;

    void handle(ChangePasswordCommand command) {
        User currentUser = authService.currentUser();
        // logic
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
class ChangePasswordCommand {

    UUID userId;
    char[] newPassword;
}

class ChangePasswordCommandHandler {

    UserRepository userRepository;

    void handle(ChangePasswordCommand command) {
         User currentUser = userRepository.findById(command.getUserId());
         // logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you talk about use cases, this is the domain of your application.
So, to answer the question, I can say: it depends on this domain.

If your domain is about the "users management" (example : LDAP application), yes! you need to implement it in your domain.

Otherwise, it's just a technical problem and you can manage it outside the domain (and call the repository directly).

Examples :

Let's assume that you have some third party authentication provider providing user structure that has the fllowing fields : id, email adddress, etc.

To just authenticate user without business rules, you can call authenticator placed in infrastruture layer from application layer.

```java
    userApplication.authenticate(String login, String password) {
        userProvider.authenticate(login, password);
    }
```

In the other hand, if you want to apply some business rules while authenticating user, you must call user domain API (interface placed in the domain layer) from application layer.

The following code is just an example. You have to clean it.

Application layer :

```java
    userApplication.authenticate(String login, String password) {
        userAPI.authenticate(login, password);
    }
```

Domain Layer :

```java
    class Member {
        ...
    }

    interface UserAPI {
        Member authenticate(login, password);
    }
```

*you can implement this interface by creating some factory or service or wathever you want. Let's say you have a Domain UserService.

```java
    class UserService implements UserAPI {
        
        UserSPI userSPI;

        Member authenticate(login, password) {
            // apply some business rules
            userSPI.authenticate(login, password);
        }
    }

    interface UserSPI {
        Member authenticate(login, password);
    }
```

Infrastructure Layer :

```java
    class MemberDTO {
        ...
    }

    class userProvider implements UserSPI {

        private final RemoteProvider remoteProvider;

        Member authenticate(login, password) {
            MemberDTO memberDTO = remoteProvider.authenticate(login, password);
            return memberMapper.dtoToDomain(memberDTO);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have some doubts. Let's assume that my application uses some third party authentication provider. This authentication provider provides user structure that has the following fields: id, email adddress, etc. On the other hand, I have Member aggregate definied in my domain, which also has an email address field. Where in this scenario should occur mapping from the user structure to the Member aggregate?

Comment: Can i have this user abstraction which only lives in the application layer or I should only operate on the member aggregate?

Comment: You don't have to put mapping logic in the domain layer. You can put it in application or infrastructure layer. I edited my response to add some examples.

Comment: I think I got it now, but for the sake of clarity, in both cases the application layer IS aware of the authentication process but decision if it's implemented there lies in my domain. If I only need to acquire the current identity (member in my case) without the entire authentication process (because I though about that in my previous comments, not really about authentication), the best solution would be to define a port (interface) in the application layer with a method such as Member getCurrentMember() and its implementation in infrastructure layer using any authentication/identity provider?

Comment: Yes. In application layer you can return MemberDTO also.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thanks a lot.