# How do i avoid, that the domain layer knows the adapters?

Tags: clean-architecture, onion-architecture

Let's say i have a usecase (business logic), an adapter (database) and a domain object. I need to call the database from my domain logic, but the question is how. The way a do it right now is by giving the domain the adapter: **(1. variant)**

```
function usecase(adapter, domain):
     domain(adapter)

function domain(adapter):
    [some logic]...
    adapter.save_to_database()
    [more logic]...

call usecase(adapter, domain)
```

Now in order to avoid letting the domain logic know the adapter, i would need to return all data and call the adapter from the usecase: **(2. variant)**

```
function usecase(adapter, domain):
     data = domain.some_logic()
     other_data = adapter.save_to_database(data)
     domain.more_logic(other_data)

call usecase()
```

So, everytime i use an adapter, i need to exit the domain, in order to call the adapter. Is that correct? If, so why is it better than the solution above?

Answer (score 1):

In your first variant, you can call the "infrastructure" layer from the domain layer. But when you call it from the domain, you have only to use an interface (@see Dependency inversion principle, API, SPI).

If you want to call the infrastructure layer from the use case (application layer), it's possible. But prefer the first solution when you have business logic in your feature.

Some rules :

- when you have business logic, use the domain layer even if you call the infrastructure layer.
- when you don't have business logic, you can call the infrastructure from the application layer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730429/clean-architecture-current-user-acquisition/62874838#62874838